# PackageManager says device doesn't have FEATURE_MIDI

Tags: android, midi

How can I write an Android app to receive MIDI events from my Yamaha YDP-113 electronic piano?

When I force it, I get a runtime error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.miditest, PID: 19022
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.midi.MidiManager
```

The hasSystemFeature() method returns false:

```
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MIDI)) {
        // do MIDI stuff
        Log.d("MainActivity-onCreate", "has MIDI feature");

        TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text_view);
        info.setText("MIDI found!");

        MidiManager m = (MidiManager) getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("MainActivity-onCreate", "cannot find MIDI feature");

        TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text_view);
        info.setText("Sorry, no MIDI");
    }
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.midi" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am sure it must be possible, because I installed "USB Midi Keyboard" by AppsTransport, which has 100,000 downloads on Google Play Store. When I play notes on my Yamaha YDP-113, the app shows which piano keyboard key I pressed, and even makes the sound!

What are the other developers using, which allows them to make apps that work with my keyboard, my MIDI-USB cable, and my Samsung tablet? Is there something I need to install on my phone? Or some package or download I need to tell gradle about?

Comment: Did you declare the feature in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes. It seems that Android Studio 3.0 is compiling my code, but I'm getting a runtime error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.midi.MidiManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MidiManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiManager.html) is only available on Android 6+. The class *and associated functionality* doesn't exist on previous releases hence the error if you run the app on older devices.

If you want to support older devices than Android 6, you're going to have to use some sort of proprietary SDK or third party library.

A quick web search suggests [kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver](https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver) may help you.

Please note that if you specify

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.midi" android:required="true"/>
```

> the app will not appear in the Play Store for old devices that do not support the MIDI API.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html

You might want to remove that line.

Comment: Thanks! Now, how do I install Mr. Shoji's USB-MIDI driver?

Comment: You don't install it. It's a library you add to your project. Read the library wiki here: https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver/wiki/How-to-setup-the-library-to-the-application

Comment: Thanks, but I've never added a library to a project before. I've only been using Android Studio for a couple of months.

Comment: @EdPoor alright then, start googling. How to declare a dependency is out of the scope. Read the wiki page linked in my previous comment, it mentions several options how to include this exact library. Pick the one that's consistent with your search results. Hint: for gradle.

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. You got me started in the right direction.